# Writing a function prototype for bootstrap dateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm new to Javascript and was trying to write a simple function prototype for Dan Grossman's bootstrap themed dateRangePicker(https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker).
I add the following code to DateRangePicker.prototype

```
setStartDate: function (startDate) {            
    alert(startDate);
},
```

and I create my daterangepicker as follows

```
var daterange = $('#reportrange').daterangepicker();
```

but when I call:

```
daterange.setStartDate(new Date());
```

I get an error saying that the object doesn't support the property or method "setStartDate".

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var reportrange = $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(),
    daterange = reportrange.data('daterangepicker');
daterange.setStartDate(new Date());
```

jQuery plugins return the jQuery object containing the selected elements, for chainability. The actual `DateRangePicker` objects are stored as a `data` property of the selected elements.